# What does "EULAID:WX.2_PRO_OEM_EN" mean in the EULA?

Tags: windows-xp

Simply put, can anyone tell me what the following line precisely means?

```
EULAID:WX.2_PRO_OEM_EN
```

It's from my Windows XP Installation CD.  I googled EULA IDs and I found quite a few other types, but not this particular ID.  I gather PRO_OEM_EN means its Windows XP Professional OEM Edition (English), and I know it's a Windows XP CD.  I've seen WX.4 but I have not seen WX.2.  I'm not sure what this line precisely means.  I don't think it's a Windows XP SP1 or SP2 CD.  I think it's the original Windows XP CD; the copyright is 2001/2002.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [forum](http://www.hardwareheaven.com/other-tech-news/4915-official-service-pack-1-download-microsoft-3.html), The WX.2 means OEM or evaluation, while WX.4 could be retail edition.

```
OEM : WX.2_PRO_OEM_EN 
EVAL: WX.2_PRO_RVL_EN 
RTL : WX.4_PRO_RTL_EN

OEM = Original Equipment Manufacturer
EVAL = Evaluation Copy 
RTL = Retail
```